# OmniGraffle - scale object proportionally

Tags: omnigraffle

Indeed there is a checkbox for `Maintain aspect ration` when you scale by value. 
But I haven't found how to scale proportionally with size grips...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try holding shift while resizing, normally works for most apps.

Comment: I tried most of the keys by now.. no good

Comment: You looked through the manual too?

Comment: Manual doesn't say much about scaling by mouse, only by value.

Comment: It seems like the official manual says that it is shift.

"Resize and keep aspect ratio ----- Select, then (shift sign)-drag a resize handle!-"

http://www.omnigroup.com/ftp/pub/software/macosx/Manuals/OmniGraffle-5-Manual.pdf

Page 97

Comment: Yes! the shift key works on Omnigraffle. Thanks, it a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively export to PDF, then import from PDF and resize.